# SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) SMTP connect() failed

Tags: email, smtp, smtpclient

I am using php mailer to send mail from smtp server. So for now  I have the code like this
in index.html code is like this

```
  <form method="post" action="email.php">
  Email: <input name="email" id="email" type="text" /><br />

  Message:<br />
  <textarea name="message" id="message" rows="15" cols="40"></textarea><br />

  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

and in email.php I have included php mailer file. So my code is like this

```
<?php
require("class.PHPMailer.php");

$email = $_REQUEST['email'] ;
$message = $_REQUEST['message'] ;

// When we unzipped PHPMailer, it unzipped to
// public_html/PHPMailer_5.2.0
require("lib/PHPMailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php");

$mail = new PHPMailer(); // create a new object
$mail->IsSMTP(); // enable SMTP
$mail->SMTPDebug = 1; // debugging: 1 = errors and messages, 2 = messages only
$mail->SMTPAuth = true; // authentication enabled
//s$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
$mail->Host = "mail.testmail.com";
$mail->Port = 25; // or 587
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Username = "mail@testname.com";
$mail->Password = "XXCCGGHHTT";
//$mail->SetFrom("myname@gmail.com");
$mail->Subject = "Test";
$mail->Body = "hello";
$mail->AddAddress("anothernae@gmail.com");
 if(!$mail->Send())
    {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
    echo "Message has been sent";
    }
```

But when I am doing submit its showing error like

```
 SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: Connection refused (111) SMTP connect() failed. Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

So can somone kindly tell me whats the error here? How to solve this issue?

Comment: Have you checked if your ISP allows connection to external server(mail.testmail.com) through port 25?